# Cassandra incorrect TTL value for select ttl()

Tags: cassandra, cql3, ttl, cassandra-2.1

**I have a 3 node cluster with replication factor : 2.**

The column family in consideration has `default_time_to_live = 3600`
Which is set using alter table :
`cqlsh:summary> alter table match with default_time_to_live=3600;`

After inserting data into columnfamily and immediately, querying, select ttl(column_name), i get incorrect results.

```
cqlsh:summary> select ttl(end_time) from match limit 5;
```

### ttl(end_time)

```
      3132
      5342
      5342
      1802
      1802
```

(5 rows)

Keyspace definition:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE summary WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Column family definition:

```
CREATE TABLE summary.match (
match_name text,
start_time bigint,
end_time bigint,
PRIMARY KEY (match_name, start_time)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start_time ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression':'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 3600
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Using :
Cassandra 2.1.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0

Should it not be something less than 3600? 
Where is the TTL value of `5342` coming in account?

Question: How does the `default_time_to_live` value come into effect?

Comment: Tested with cassandra 2.1.0 and ttl is always as expected (<= 3600). The property default_time_to_live is the default ttl for all rows in this column familly.

Comment: @Guillaume - For a single node ttl is expected (<= 3600), for 2 node cluster, with RF=2, still ttl is expected (<=3600) always. As soon as i move to 3 nodes or more, with RF=2, i am getting incorrect ttl. This also happens when i insert/update data using `using ttl`. Does RF has to do something with this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure the unexpected ttl values haven't been inserted with a different `default_time_to_live` setting before?

Comment: Yes. It turned out the nodes were out of sync. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-issue. 
The timestamps of node in the cluster was out of sync.

Running `ntpdate -bu <ntp server>` to sync clocks in each node.
Then TTL is coming as expected.

Some reading onto why syncing time is important for cassandra.

https://blog.logentries.com/2014/03/synchronizing-clocks-in-a-cassandra-cluster-pt-1-the-problem/

https://ria101.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/cassandra-the-importance-of-system-clocks-avoiding-oom-and-how-to-escape-oom-meltdown/